# Is there a collection of default height for Android Material Design?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-design-library

I have been studied Material Design for Android.

I found that there are many default height.

e.g.

https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html
https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

But those resource is not in the format for Android developer.

I want something like default-dimen.xml

Is there any project, dimen.xml that store all those default height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use dimen resources begin with md

e.g.

@dimen/md_button_padding_horizontal

for more default Material design layout dimen

https://gist.github.com/umitems/095c86666246c3f32a4e

ref.https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Answer (score 0):

Default colors and dimens per Material Design guidelines and Android Design guidelines:

https://github.com/DmitryMalkovich/material-design-dimens

Example

```
@dimen/material_layout_keylines_screen_edge_margin
@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [material-components/material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) github repository has styles defined, that you can also use for your views.